# No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()) although Firebase is being initialized

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I have a firebase_service.dart file when I create references to all my services. The code for that is here

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

class FirebaseService {
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  FirebaseService();
}
```

However I receive this error - *Exception has occurred.
FirebaseException ([core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp())*

In my main.dart file I have initialized firebase as seen below

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); //Ensures app is initialized first
  await Firebase.initializeApp; 
  GetIt.instance.registerSingleton<FirebaseService>(
    FirebaseService(),
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

However I am seeing a squiggly line under the await keyword and this is the comment - *'await' applied to 'Future Function({String? name, FirebaseOptions? options})', which is not a 'Future'*

Could that be the issue? I am not so sure what is wrong here

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem. My Android application is working fine but when using IOS application it's throw this type of exception. make sure you have added GoogleServices-info.plist file in your ios project and google-service.json android folder. If it's not solve your issue then use this code. Also make sure you have configure Android project as per documentation. You have to add dependency in build.gradle.(When you add app in firebase you will get instruction). if all above change not working then in your main.dart

```
if (Platform.isIOS) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: FirebaseOptions(
            apiKey: "your api key Found in GoogleService-info.plist",
            appId: "Your app id found in Firebase",
            messagingSenderId: "Your Sender id found in Firebase",
            projectId: "Your Project id found in Firebase"));
  } else {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  }
```

Comment: Issue is that i am working on windows and so have not set up anything for ios. Could that be an issue?

Comment: No It's not an issue. make sure you follow firebase for android tutorial also. and check google-service.json file is valid